# Wireshark - Can't open preferences file "/home/guest/.config/wireshark/preferences": Permission denied

Tags: permissions, interface, wireshark, capture

First usage, when opening the Capture Interfaces Options the pop up goes 'Can't open preferences file "/home/guest/.config/wireshark/preferences": Permission denied.'

Installation was successful with:

```
sudo apt-get install wireshark
```

Tried to solve the issue with the followings:

```
sudo adduser $USER wireshark
```

and then again with:

```
sudo setcap 'CAP_NET_RAW+eip CAP_NET_ADMIN+eip' /usr/bin/dumpcap
```

Tried as well launching wireshark both as user or root.

Comment: I presume that `guest` is *not* the Guest User account, and is an actual user?  Have you made sure that `/home/guest/.config/wireshark` is recursively owned by the user, then logged out and back in?

Comment: yes, 'guest' is the user name.

Comment: no more dialog message with: sudo chown -R guest:wireshark /home/guest/.config/wireshark - thank you